# Is this function differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: limits, derivatives, solution-verification, proof-writing, absolute-value

Here is my prood to see if this function is differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$.

$$f(x) = \vert x\vert x$$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)\vert x+h \vert - x\vert x \vert}{h} & = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{x\vert x+h \vert + h \vert x + h\vert - x\vert x \vert }{h}
\\\\
& = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{x\vert x \vert + x\vert h\vert + h \vert x \vert + h\vert h \vert - x\vert x \vert}{h}
\\\\
& =  \lim_{h\to 0} x \dfrac{\vert h \vert}{h} + \vert x \vert + \vert h \vert
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Now the last term is zero. The middle term is just $\vert x \vert $ and the first one now depends on the direction:

$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} x \dfrac{\vert h \vert}{h} = x$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0^-} x \dfrac{\vert h \vert}{h} = -x$$

Consequently, the limits are different (here $x$ can be whatever number), hence the function exhibits an angular point at every $x$ in the domain.

This concludes the function is not differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now it looks weird to me, maybe I'm right or perhaps I'm wrong.

Asking you for help in case!

Comment: Obviously differentiable at $x$ for $x \neq 0$. Prove that it is differentiable at $0$ also.

Comment: You have been using extensively the **false** identity $\lvert x+h\rvert=\lvert x\rvert+\lvert h\rvert$, and of course there is little point in addressing stuff after a mistake of algebra in, like, line 2.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio The identity is true when $x$ and $h$ have the same sign. Yet I recognize there I cannot know what $x$ is and I have to split better then I use directional limits for $h$, so I shall review it all and treat different cases...

Comment: @Numb3rs If $x>0$, for $|h|$ small enough, $|x+h| = x+h$. Similarly, if $x<0$ and $|h|$ small enough, $|x+h| = -(x+h)$. This should be helpful for your computations.

Comment: @Didier Oh thanks, that helps indeed a bit!

Comment: You can also note for $x<0$ this function is $-x^2$ and for $x>0$ it's $x^2$ both of which satisfy $f(0)=f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments you received, we consider the three cases:

- $x >>0$
- $x << 0$
- $x = 0$

**Case 1, $x >>0$**

Here then $\vert x+ h \vert = x + h$ hence

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)^2 - x^2}{h} & = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{2hx + h^2}{h}
\\\\
& = \lim_{h\to 0} 2x + h \longrightarrow 2x
\end{split}
\end{equation}

**Case 2, $x << 0$**

Here then $\vert x+ h \vert = -(x + h)$ hence

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{-(x+h)^2 + x^2}{h} & = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{-2hx - h^2}{h}
\\\\
& = \lim_{h\to 0} -2x - h \longrightarrow -2x
\end{split}
\end{equation}

**Case 3, $x = 0$**

Here then $\vert x+ h \vert =  h$ hence

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{h\vert h \vert}{h} & = \lim_{h\to 0} \vert h\vert 
\\\\
& \longrightarrow 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Whence the function $f(x) = x\vert x\vert$ is differentiable over all $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use that $x\mapsto|x|$ and $x\mapsto x$ are differentiable for every $x\neq0$ to conclude that $f$ is differentiable for $x\neq0$.

To see derivability at $0$ consider
$$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$
and see that it tends to zero as $h\to 0$.